# Creating database user with domain in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, createuser

I want to create a database User in C#. In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I just can create one with the following command:

```
CREATE USER [DOMAIN\user]
```

But when I try to do the same in C# I can't send a single backslash in the command.

```
string query = @"CREATE USER [DOMAIN\user]";
```

I already tried things like `query.Replace("\\\\", "\\")` or `query.Replace(@"\\\\", @"\\")`, but nothing worked for me. I always get an error with:

> Incorrect syntax near '\\'.

It's the same like I would write `CREATE USER [DOMAIN\\\\user]` in SQL Server Management Studio.

Somehow I can't transfer just one backslash in the query.

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Thats my actual code:

```
public SqlConnection Conn;    
public bool CreateUser(string LoginName)
{
    string dom_login = Domain + "\\" + LoginName;
    string query = @"CREATE USER [" + dom_login.Replace("\\",@"\") + "]";

    // now query should be okay, so send to sql connection
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
         Conn.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sDataAsp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, Conn);          
        sDataAsp.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Here i get the syntax error
        string error = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you send a single backslash, should work with `@`, what error are you seeing? Double is defo wrong unless you don't use `@`, in which case you don't need `Replace`

Comment: i just get the error: Incorrect syntax near '\\'.

Comment: Creating domain users obviously works. SSMS doesn't use any system or API calls, it uses SQL commands too. Post your actual code and actual errors if any.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near '\\'.` because you added an extra slash when only one was needed. The string replacements, if they worked, would only make things worse.Luckily, they don't as you're trying to replace 2 or 4 backslashes with 1 or two respectively.

Comment: You've asked this question before and you were asked for additional information. There is clearly something odd about your code, because the methods you use for string escaping work in general. So show the  exact code which you are using.

Comment: `CREATE USER [Contoso\Fritz] ` works. So does `string query = @"CREATE USER [DOMAIN\user]";`. We can't guess how you tried to execute the commands though, or what errors you got. You certainly **didn't** get `Incorrect syntax near '\\'.` because there's only  single backslash there. Post the *original* code and error

Comment: i added my actual code, i hope you now see clearly what i'm trying.

Comment: Well, I don't think you should be using a SqlDataAdaptor *The SqlDataAdapter serves as a bridge between a DataSet and SQL Server for retrieving and saving data.*  - you are trying to execute SQL which is something else. I would be using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: but it should work, even when i only got one or zero rows, it works for example with the query = "select name, database_id from sys.databases", then i of course get rows, but with create user i expect to just modify the table

Comment: *Its should work* - why? Its clearly designed to connect to a datatable - who knows what its doing under the hood. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: i edited again, but SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery didn't solve the problem.

Comment: somehow query still contains two backslashes

Comment: The query doesn't contain 2 backslashes, the debugger shows 2 backslashes because thats how a backslash is escaped in a string, i.e. 2 backslashes is actually only a single backslash escaped.

Comment: I just ran both of your code blocks and they both work, creating me a new user. And your code can be simplified to `string dom_login = Domain + @"\" + LoginName; string query = @"CREATE USER [" + dom_login + "]";`.

Comment: i see, but why do i get the same error everytime, it just transferes with two backslashes

Comment: I can only imagine that your actual code is more complex than shown and something else is interfering? Are you running under ASP.NET? WinForms? Something else? Can you access the database with a create user command that doesn't require a backslash? I assume when you put a breakpoint on it shows `query = "Domain\\User"`?

Comment: thank you! i guess i had some trouble with @ or sth, because now it works

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

```
private bool ExecuteQuery(string domain, string user)
{
    try
    {
        string dom_login = domain + @"\" + user; 
        string query = @"CREATE USER [" + dom_login + "]";
        if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            Conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thats nuts, because that is identical in function to your posted code - I used your posted code first, before changing it to this, and both worked. Oh well at least its working.

Comment: ye i know it's strange, but thanks for help